# ReactNative: How to center number in circle

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to create badge element to show some countings.
But faced the problem with aligning.
I've added both `alignItems` and `justifyContent`, but my number still not centered.

I've colored background of `<Text>` and found out that element is centered, but probably something with font (because of additional horizontal spacing). I'm using `Open Sans`. I've dumped font with Apple Font Tool Suite to show if there's a problem with font.

Can somebody help with solving this issue?

The code of element:

```
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
          width: 14,
          height: 14,
          borderRadius: 7,
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 8,
            lineHeight: 12,
            color: '#323643',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF8D9',
          }}
        >
          {2}
        </Text>
      </View>
```

Screen of result:

[image: Link to image]

(*I know that quality is not good, but I needed to show that there're some additional spacing*)

extracted properies of Open Sans:

```
<hheaTable
    versionMajor="1"
    versionMinor="0"
    ascender="2189"
    descender="-600"
    lineGap="0"
    advanceWidthMax="2476"
    minLeftSideBearing="-1126"
    minRightSideBearing="-389"
    xMaxExtent="2466"
    caretSlopeRise="1"
    caretSlopeRun="0"
    caretOffset="0"
    metricDataFormat="0"
    numberOfHMetrics="931"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it is related to your font gap, several time I faced to something like this and you cannot purely fix it.

You should add `paddingLeft` to `Text` component. if you faced to this issue just on iOS or Android you can use `Platform.OS` to distinguish the style.

Comment: It will work, I guess. But I need to add `paddingLeft: 1` for number **2**. But if i have number **28** (for example) then there's no padding for this case.

Comment: @kimoofey, I know, bug comes from issue of font, but we should fix it, even with shitty solution, add a function for understanding it has one digit or not, for one digit numbers pass `paddingLeft: 1` and for rest of them pass `paddingLeft: 0`.